# JavaFX ComboBoxCellColumn get value

Tags: java, javafx, tableview

I have a TableView which displays multiple columns, one of these uses ComboBoxTableCell to display a list of options. I can select the options, however when trying to print them out from the table they are all null.

Here is the column

```
    BookDogSelectRunCol.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Dog, String>("bookingRun"));

    BookDogSelectRunCol.setCellFactory(ComboBoxTableCell.forTableColumn(runOptions));

    BookDogTableView.setItems(customersDogs);
```

Then i have a method which retrieves the data from the combobox column

```
    for(int loop = 0; loop < BookDogTableView.getItems().size(); loop ++){

        //if(!BookDogSelectRunCol.getCellData(loop).equals(null)){
            System.out.println(BookDogSelectRunCol.getText());          
            //}
```

However this returns null. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You get the values from the model, not from the column. I.e. `for (Dog dog : bookDogTableView.getItems()) { System.out.println(dog.getBookingRun());}`

Comment: @James_D how would i set the value for dog.setBookingRun when editing the combobox?

Comment: Assuming you have your model class set up correctly (i.e. following the [JavaFX properties pattern](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/properties-binding-tutorial/binding.htm#JFXBD107)), the `ComboBoxTableCell` will do that for you.

Comment: @James_D thank you so much, was stuck on that for hours.